# Can you apply Jquery such as hide(), fadeOut(), show(), fadeIn(), etc to function itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you apply effects such as fadeOut() to the function itself? or you have to target elements itself?

Here an example is it possible to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Intro();
  function Intro() {
    $("<p id='hide'>Can you add effect to the function or only for element such as hide to the id left of me!</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder")
  }
  $(Intro()).hide();
  $("#hide").hide();
})
```

I do notice that if you comment out the $(Intro()).hide(); There nothing on screen. if you comment out the $("#hide").hide(); There is double of sentences, yet leave both alone and/or comment out, it will just leave it at one sentence as it should be.

https://jsfiddle.net/Necrorifter/x6hcswtb/21/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of what's happening in your code. On the line where you call `Intro()`, it's running your `Intro` function, which inserts your `hide` paragraph. Worth noting is that `Intro()` doesn't *return* anything, so the result if calling `Intro()` is `undefined`, though it does produce the side effect of inserting content into your page.

Therefore, when you call `$(Intro()).hide()` next, that's going to again cause your side effect, inserting the paragraph again, but effectively you're doing `$(undefined).hide()` after that, not what you want.

I believe what you *really* want is:

```
function Intro() {
  return (
    $("<p id='hide'>Can you add effect to the function or only for element such as hide to the id left of me!</p>")
      .insertBefore("#placeholder")
  );
}

const intro = Intro();
intro.hide();
```

^- Here, you're only calling `Intro()` once so the content is only inserted once, and you're *returning* the created element so something can be done with it later on.

Comment: Unforunate, i am still getting that double sentence when attempt to link the intro.hide(); to a button using (document).on("click","button", function(){ intro.hide();}); But regardless of that error. the whole const intro = Intro(); is what I was looking for, so thank you for your assistance unlike other stroller. I will experiment with concept of return to see if I can get it to be of uses to me.